# Entity Framework SqlQuery to list - The data reader has more than one field

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to fetch data from table, I have few properties in my model.

```
string query = "Select * From CompanyInfoes where SpecialNumber = @specialNumber";

var objVendor = Db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
```

The way i do it but after all recieved an error:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

Is there a way to fetch data from table and put all properties into list or array ? I've used simillar method to queries with only one property but now I have to fetch few.

Comment: change `Db.Database.SqlQuery<string>` to `Db.Database.SqlQuery<CompanyInfo>`

Comment: Please check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901324/7960700

Comment: I'm not that familiar with entity-framework, but I think the error message is pretty clear - you should use a mapped object instead of a string.

Comment: Instead of * in your query try to specify only single column name.